# Less file is not getting compiled in Visual Studio 2013 Preview using Web Esssentials 2013 Preview Extension

Tags: less, web-essentials, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio 2013 preview version and I am trying to use less files in my application. But I am getting a compile error in the right pane. you can just have a look at it.Can anyone help me out?
[image: Error]

Comment: i don't actually understand how you installed web essentials 2013 -- i can't find it from the "extensions and updates" gallery in vs2013...

Comment: You can just check this link. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361

Comment: The day actually when I was trying to execute this ,we were not having the correct update of Web Essentials Preview 2013.The next day itself i.e on july 19th 2013 Microsoft has released Web Essentials 2013 fully updated.I got my error solved.Thanks to Microsoft.No you can find it in extensions and updates.Check correctly

Comment: I think my problem is that I'm using the Express version, which apparently does not allow useful extensions... *frowny face*

Answer (score 2):

You have to save the less file with "Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) Codepage 65001" encoding.  Go to File->Save "yourfile" as.

Comment: No it was not the problem. It was problem with Web Essentials Update.Though thanks for the help.

Comment: @BharatBhushan have you fixed the problem?